# Calling a view to function same as a Dialog box

Tags: c#

I'm trying to call an existing view/form in my program, but I want it to wait there in the code where I called it until I'm finished with the view I just called. Similar as to how one would invoke a Dialog box with a question and then only continuing after that dialog box closes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form.ShowDialog

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx